# How to write custom errors and return messages with error keyword Solidity

Tags: error-handling, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I tried to make a custom error but it doesn't return a message to revert
How could I make it return a message?

```
/// custom error
error MyCustomError(address _address);

if user { revert MyCustomError({address: msg.sender}) }
```

I got this error

```
Runtime error: revert
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors:

1- `if` statement should be inside a function

2- when you defined the custom error,you defined the named parameter as `_address`

```
contract Test {
    address public user;
    /// custom error
    error MyCustomError(address _address);

    function revertError() public view {
    // I just had to pass a valid condition. address(0)=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    // if(user) would give this error: "Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool"
    if(user!=address(0)) 
    { 
        revert MyCustomError({_address: msg.sender});
        }
    }
 }
```